# Javascript : Reject csv with more than one column

Tags: javascript

I have to do validation on csv where file should be rejected if it has more than 1 columns. Is there any regular expression i can use or any other way to check for all delimiters. As of now I am trying to :

```
const reader = new FileReader();
let data = [];
reader.onload = (e) => { 
      const data = e.target.result;
}
let validInd = true;
for (const email of data) {
     if (email.search(',') !== -1) {
          validInd = false;
          break;
      }
 }
```

Please don't go with exact code , assume file is read and list created out of each line is stored in 'data'. 'data' for csv with 2 columns will have something like:

```
data = ['dilask1@gmail.com, dilask1@gmail.com', 'dilask2@gmail.com, dilask1@gmail.com']
```

with one column:

```
data = ['dilask1@gmail.com', 'dilask2@gmail.com']
```

Above code will only validate if csv is comma separated , do we have generic check to something which will allow me reject csv file having more than one column with any delimeter, if not, what is the standard logic.

Comment: Is that your actual code, as your using data out of scope here.

Comment: just modified for this problem , assume it is in scope , editing the question